# Custom breadcrumb UI for d3.js treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with d3 treemap layout. The code is in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-treemap-wfbtg?file=/src/treegraph.js.
The current breadcrumb of d3 treemap looks like the one below.
[image]

I need to customise to the one like this.
[image]

In the above image on clicking A2 node the breadcrumb should be **A > A2** and on clicking the B1 node it should be **B > B1**. The categorization is in the hierarchical json data. In the json, the name for the node is B - B1 , A- A1 , B- B2, so B1 and B2 comes under category B, A1 and A2 comes under A. Is it possible to customise the breadcrumb of d3 treemap.

Comment: Can you please check my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to incorporate custom breadcrumb you need to modify the name method inside your code.

I have updated the code and changed the name method (Line 77) in your code as below:

```
const name = d => {
  let labelstring = "";
  const ancestors = d.ancestors().reverse();
  if (ancestors.length === 1) {
    labelstring = ancestors[0].data.name;
  } else if (ancestors.length > 1) {
    labelstring = ancestors
      .slice(1)
      .map(d => d.data.name.split("-").join(" > "))
      .join(", ");
  }
  return labelstring;
};
```

You can check and let me know if it is what you need.

Working code line: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-treemap-kkrho?file=/src/treegraph.js

Thanks!

Comment: @PrincelsNinja do you have a solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108153/node-with-less-value-looks-big-in-d3-treemap