# Node with less value looks big in d3 treemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In d3 treemap I want to represent the tiles of the treemap based on the values of thehierarchical data. Large value occupies should have large tile. My code is in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-kowalevski-or9bk?file=/src/treegraph.js . Here the **B-B1** has larger value than **B-B2** but in the chart **B-B2** having larger tile. Attached the scrrenshot
[image]